# Application: University degree

Tags: articles

Are the following two sentences grammatically correct?

1. I completed my bachelor's and master's degree at Delaware University.
2. I had an almost perfect grade of 9 in my master's degree.
3. Distributed systems was my focus of my master's degree.

References that I found frequently use different articles for the degree:
*a bachelor's degree* or *my bachelor's degree*.
For the other sentences, I did not found any suitable references.

Comment: The choice of determiners (the class that articles are in) is certainly correct. I'd make "degree**s**" plural in the first sentence though.

Comment: @gotube Thanks your answer. Does not "degree" refer to bachelor's and master's, but not both? In other words, "degree" is an omitted noun. The full sentence would be: I completed my bachelor's degree and master's degree at Delaware University. I thought a repeated use of "degree" is stylistically cumbersome.

Comment: @user148865 As you have written it, it sounds as though there is a combined degree known as **a bachelor's and master's degree**..  Follow gotube's advice.

Comment: Thanks, then I'll do that. The second sentence is also correct? I did not found any references combining explict grades with degrees.

Comment: You might phrase it slightly differently: **I achieved a grade 9 in my master's degree.** Note that academic degrees, used in a general sense, as in your example, are not capitalised. But you will often find them capitalised in university brochures and publicity. By the way **I did not FIND..** NOT **I did not found..**

Comment: I added a third sentence.

Comment: @RonaldSole Thanks for your answer. Would it change if I slightly rephrase it as "I achieved an almost perfect grade of 9 in my master's degree."

Comment: Adding further queries is not recommended practice. But, if Distributed Systems is a particular subject or title, use capitals. If it is merely a description use lower case. In your example, I should write: **Distributed Systems was the focus of my master's degree.** (Not **my focus**.)

Comment: Last comment. We are not supposed to give writing advice. It sounds boastful. I should let the result stand for itself. But this is merely an opinion.

Comment: @gotube didn't tell you to repeat 'degree', but to say _my bachelor's and master's degrees_.

Comment: Thank you your advices. @gotube  feel free to write an answer and I will then accept it.